# DES Serialization Exception

Tags: vb.net, serialization, encryption, des

I am  and am having some trouble deserializing an object with DES cryptography.

I am getting an exception that says "Bad Data." in the `DeserializeDESObjectFromFile` function.

Can I please have some help to get this working?

Here is my code:

```
    Public Sub SerializeDESObjectToFile(FileName As String, Item As Object)
    Dim fs As FileStream
    Dim formatter As New BinaryFormatter

    Dim DESKey() As Byte = {200, 5, 78, 232, 9, 6, 0, 4}
    Dim DESInitializationVector() As Byte = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9}
    Dim MyStreamEncrypter As CryptoStream = Nothing

    fs = New FileStream(FileName, FileMode.Create)
    Dim DESAlgorithm As DES
    DESAlgorithm = New DESCryptoServiceProvider
    MyStreamEncrypter = New CryptoStream(fs, DESAlgorithm.CreateEncryptor(DESKey, DESInitializationVector), CryptoStreamMode.Write)

    Try
        formatter.Serialize(MyStreamEncrypter, Item)
    Catch e As Exception
        Console.WriteLine("Failed to serialize. Reason: " & e.Message)
    Finally
        fs.Close()
    End Try
End Sub

Public Function DeserializeDESObjectFromFile(FileName As String) As Object
    Dim fs As New FileStream(FileName, FileMode.Open)
    Dim ItemToReturn As New Object

    Dim DESKey() As Byte = {200, 5, 78, 232, 9, 6, 0, 4}
    Dim DESInitializationVector() As Byte = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9}
    Dim MyStreamDecrypter As CryptoStream = Nothing

    Dim DESAlgorithm As DES
    DESAlgorithm = New DESCryptoServiceProvider

    MyStreamDecrypter = New CryptoStream(fs, DESAlgorithm.CreateDecryptor(DESKey, DESInitializationVector), CryptoStreamMode.Read)

    Try
        Dim formatter As New BinaryFormatter
        ItemToReturn = DirectCast(formatter.Deserialize(MyStreamDecrypter), Object)
        Return ItemToReturn
    Catch e As Exception
        MsgBox(e.Message)
        Return Nothing
    Finally
        fs.Close()
    End Try
End Function
```

Comment: Only use indications of your IDE (visual studio) in the tags if it can be of influence on the question/asnwer itself. Use often used tags, e.g. use [tag:encryption] instead of just [tag:des] to get more attention.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is important to make sure that the last block in the stream is flushed. Block ciphers modes such as ECB mode and CBC mode need to be padded because a block cipher can only encrypt full blocks of plaintext. As the stream does not know that your serialized data object is the last data it has to encrypt, it cannot pad and encrypt the last block itself.

The [FlushFinalBlock](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.cryptostream.flushfinalblock.aspx) should be called after you have written the last plain text data to the `CryptoStream`. Alternatively you could call `close()` on the upper `CryptoStream` instead of the underlying stream, or make sure it is properly disposed *before* you call `close()` on the underlying stream.

Comment: If a C .NET expert could check the last line then that would be appreciated. I'm reasonably sure reading the API, but that's about as far as my knowledge goes.